# How to UnPivot for multiple columns SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

In my application, I have used store product description values as follows:

```
ID  BILLNO    CUS_NAME     DATE         TOT_BAL  S1 S2  S3  S4      D1  D2  D3  D4      Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4      U1  U2  U3  U4      T1   T2     T3  T4  TOTAL   CUSCODE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
29  1         XXX          Apr-03-2017  1932     1  2   3   NULL    AAA BBB CCC NULL    6   30  6   NULL    80  35  67  NULL    480  1050   402 0   1932    DF
40  2         YYYY         Apr-04-2017  6454     1  2   3   NULL    AAA DDD FFF NULL    30  24  50  NULL    80  96  35  NULL    2400 2304  1750 0   6454    MQ    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am migrating my application to latest technologies, so i am re structuring mt tables to avoid complications. So i want the result would be to adapt my new table as follows:

```
  BILLNO  CUS_NAME  DATE         TOT_BAL SNO  Pdt  QTY  Unit  Tot  CUSCODE
  1       XXX       Apr-03-2017  1932    1    AAA  6    80    480  DF
  1       XXX       Apr-03-2017  1932    2    BBB  30   35   1050  DF
  1       XXX       Apr-03-2017  1932    3    CCC  6    67    402  DF
  2       YYY       Apr-04-2017  6454    1    AAA  30   80   2400  MQ
  2       YYY       Apr-04-2017  6454    2    DDD  24   96   2304  MQ
  2       YYY       Apr-04-2017  6454    3    FFF  50   35   1750  MQ
```

I tried below query but its giving wrong result:

I don't want Null values. I just need to have valid data only. For Example S4, D4, Q4 are Null values , so Output should ignore that.

```
SELECT BILLNO, CUS_NAME,SNOA,SNO,PDTA,PDT
FROM [tmpFormat]
UNPIVOT
(
  SNO
  FOR SNOA IN (S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6,S7,S8,S9,S10,S11,S12,S13,S14,S15,S16,S17)
) UnPIV
UNPIVOT
(
  PDT
  FRO PDTA IN (D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9,D10,D11,D12,D13,D14,D15,D16,D17)
) UnPiv1;
```

Comment: I'd suggest your target table has its own issues - you're storing data that *should* be the same now across multiple rows. My own suggestion would be to use two tables - one for the "header" (the common values) and one for the "line items". And stop *storing* calculable data (TOT_BAL) unless you can demonstrate a performance need for it to be stored.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, I have the two table as you suggested, but here i have mentioned only detailed table. I will store the common information in Header table only. Please help me out

Answer (score 3):

Try  CROSS APPLY

```
SELECT BILLNO, CUS_NAME, UnP.SNOA, UnP.PDTA --,..
FROM [tmpFormat]
CROSS APPLY
( SELECT S1 AS SNOA, D1 as PDTA --,..
  UNION ALL
  SELECT S2 AS SNOA, D2 as PDTA --,.. 
 -- ..
) UnP
```

Comment: Or `CROSS APPLY (VALUES (1, S1, D1, Q1, U1, T1),(2, S2, D2, Q2, U2, T2),(3, S3, D3, Q3, U3, T3),(4, S4, D4, Q4, U4, T4)) UnP (index, SNO, Pdt, QTY, Unit, Tot)`

Answer (score 0):

You can unpivot it manually :

```
select BILLNO, CUS_NAME, DATE, TOT_BAL, S1 as SNO, D1 as Pdt, Q1 as QTY, U1 as Unit, T1 as Tot, CUSCODE
from [tmpFormat]
union all
select BILLNO, CUS_NAME, DATE, TOT_BAL, S2, D2, Q2, U2, T2, CUSCODE
from [tmpFormat]
union all
select BILLNO, CUS_NAME, DATE, TOT_BAL, S3, D3, Q3, U3, T3, CUSCODE
from [tmpFormat]
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Query UnPivoting:

Using Sys.Columns and Stuff(Dynamic Querying) to concatenate | grouping the multiple columns(need to be appended) values under a single column.

Example S1, S2, S3...... as SNO

Later dynamic query is processed with Unpivot to convert multiple column data to the single row.
Example D1, D2, D3..... under the column PDT with ID to map with the static data.

Dynamic queries results are stored in the Table variables for later processing.

Table variables created are used with CTE's to join Unpivoted data with static data to get the final result.

```
    If OBJECT_ID('UnpivotData','u') is not null
     Drop table UnPivotData
    go
    Create table UnPivotData
    (
    Id int,
    BILLNO int,
    Cus_Name varchar(10),
    [Date] date,
    Tot_Bal Int,
    S1 smallint,
    S2 smallint,
    S3 smallint,
    S4 smallint,
    D1 varchar(3),
    D2 varchar(3),
    D3 varchar(3),
    D4 varchar(3),
    Q1 smallint,
    Q2 smallint,
    Q3 smallint,
    Q4 smallint,
    U1 smallint,
    U2 smallint,
    U3 smallint,
    U4 smallint,
    T1 smallint,
    T2 smallint,
    T3 smallint,
    T4 smallint,
    Total int,
    CusCode varchar(2)
    )

    insert into UnPivotData
    Select 29, 1, 'XXX', '03-04-2017', 1932, 1, 2, 3, NULL, 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', NULL, 6, 30, 6, NULL, 80, 35, 67, NULL, 480, 1050, 402, 0, 1932, 'DF'
    union
    Select 40, 2,'YYY', '04-04-2017', 6454, 1, 2, 3, NULL, 'AAA', 'DDD', 'FFF', NULL, 30, 24, 50, NULL, 80, 96, 35, NULL, 2400, 2304, 1750, 0, 6454, 'MQ'


    DECLARE @SNO AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='',@PDT  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='',@QTY  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='', @UNIT  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='', @TOT  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)=''

    SET @SNO = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QuoteName(C.name)
                from sys.tables T join sys.columns C on T.object_id=C.object_id and T.object_id=OBJECT_ID('UnPivotData','U') and C.Name like'S'+'[0-9]%'
                 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
    SET @PDT = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QuoteName(C.name)
                from sys.tables T join sys.columns C on T.object_id=C.object_id and T.object_id=OBJECT_ID('UnPivotData','U') and C.Name like'D'+'[0-9]%'
                 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
    SET @QTY = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QuoteName(C.name)
               from sys.tables T join sys.columns C on T.object_id=C.object_id and T.object_id=OBJECT_ID('UnPivotData','U') and C.Name like'Q'+'[0-9]%'
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
    SET @UNIT = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QuoteName(C.name)
                from sys.tables T join sys.columns C on T.object_id=C.object_id and T.object_id=OBJECT_ID('UnPivotData','U') and C.Name like'U'+'[0-9]%'
                 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
    SET @TOT = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QuoteName(C.name)
                from sys.tables T join sys.columns C on T.object_id=C.object_id and T.object_id=OBJECT_ID('UnPivotData','U') and C.Name like'T'+'[0-9]%'
                 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

    Declare @Query1 Nvarchar(MAX),@Query2 Nvarchar(MAX),@Query3 Nvarchar(MAX),@Query4 Nvarchar(MAX),@Query5 Nvarchar(MAX)

    Set @Query1='select ID,SNO  from
         (
         Select ID,'+@SNO+' from UnPivotData
         )L
         unpivot
         (
            SNo for col in('+ @SNO +')
         ) u'

    Set @Query2='select ID,PDT  from
         (
         Select ID,'+@PDT+' from UnPivotData
         )L
         unpivot
         (
            PDT for col in('+ @PDT +')
         ) u'

    Set @Query3='select ID,QTY  from
         (
         Select ID,'+@QTY+' from UnPivotData
         )L
         unpivot
         (
            QTY for col in('+ @QTY +')
         ) u'

    Set @Query4='select ID,UNIT  from
         (
         Select ID,'+@UNIT+' from UnPivotData
         )L
         unpivot
         (
            UNIT for col in('+ @UNIT +')
         ) u'

    Set @Query5='select ID, TOT  from
        (
        Select ID,'+@TOT+' from UnPivotData
        )L
        unpivot
        (
        TOT for col in('+ @TOT +')
        ) u'


    Declare @t1 table
    (
    id int,
    SNO Smallint
    )
    Declare @t2 table
    (
    id int,
    PDT Varchar(3)
    )
    Declare @t3 table
    (
    id int,
    QTY Smallint
    )
    Declare @t4 table
    (
    id int,
    UNIT Smallint
    )
    Declare @t5 table
    (
    id int,
    TOT Smallint
    )
    Insert into @T1 execute ( @Query1 )
    Insert into @T2 execute ( @Query2 )
    Insert into @T3 execute ( @Query3 )
    Insert into @T4 execute ( @Query4 )
    Insert into @T5 execute ( @Query5 )


    ;With Cte
    as
    (
    Select UD.Id,BILLNO,Cus_Name,[Date],Tot_Bal,SNO,Row_Number() over(partition by T1.ID Order by T1.ID)Row_NO--,PDT,QTY,UNIT,TOT
    ,Total,CusCode
    from UnPivotData UD join @t1 T1  on UD.Id=T1.id
    )
    ,
    Cte1
    as
    (
    Select Cte.*,PDT from Cte Join
    (Select *,Row_Number() over(partition by ID Order by ID)Row_NO from  @t2) T2 on Cte.ID=T2.ID and Cte.Row_NO=T2.Row_NO
    )
    ,
    Cte2
    as
    (
    Select Cte1.*,QTY from Cte1 Join
    (Select *,Row_Number() over(partition by ID Order by ID)Row_NO from  @t3) T3 on Cte1.ID=T3.ID and Cte1.Row_NO=T3.Row_NO
    )
    ,
    Cte3
    as
    (
    Select Cte2.*,UNIT from Cte2 Join
    (Select *,Row_Number() over(partition by ID Order by ID)Row_NO from  @t4) T4 on Cte2.ID=T4.ID and Cte2.Row_NO=T4.Row_NO
    )
    ,
    Cte4
    as
    (
    Select Cte3.*,TOT from Cte3 Join
    (Select *,Row_Number() over(partition by ID Order by ID)Row_NO from  @t5) T5 on Cte3.ID=T5.ID and Cte3.Row_NO=T5.Row_NO
    )
    Select Id,BILLNO,Cus_Name,[Date],Tot_Bal,SNO,PDT,QTY,UNIT,TOT
    ,Cuscode
     from Cte4
```